# Strip Map Index Tool: output has no geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, strip-map

I'm having a problem creating a grid index in ArcMap. I'm encountering the same problem with both the Strip Map Index Features (first choice) and Grid Index tools.

Steps:

1. Open the Strip Map Index Features tool in the Cartography toolbox.
2. Specify a line feature as input and set output to default geodatabase.

Result:

--Output features were generated, but have no geometry. "Shape_Length" and "Shape_Area" (as well as "TopPage" and "BottomPage") fields in attribute table contain null values. Symbology is set, but there's nothing to display.

I get a comparable result when I attempt to use the Grid Index Features tool.

System:
ArcGIS 10.2.1 (Basic license) | Windows 10 (64-bit)

---

*I was able to work around this problem by creating a whole new MXD and adding all my data back in by hand. Not a definitive solution by any means.*

Comment: May be you have the extent environment setting set and the result is that it attempts to build indices but outside the extent so nothing is generated?